# link_to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola quiero guardar  con link_to ya que  guardo mas atributos con este.

input

t.string :provecancela

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@reunion) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input
    :provecancela,
    label: "Por que cancela",
    as: :text,
    input_html: { :style=> 'resize: none;', size: "5x5", maxlength: 300, title: 'Cancelar' },
    placeholder: "Por que cancela"
  %>  
  <%= f.button :submit, "guardar", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  <%= link_to 'Cancelar', cancelprov_path(@reunion.id), data: { confirm: 'Está seguro de cancelar' } %> 
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'reuniones/:id/cancelprov' => 'reuniones#cancelprov', as: :cancelprov
```

**reuniones_controller.rb**

```
  class ReunionesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_reunion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     load_and_authorize_resource

 def index


   @q = Reunion.ransack(params[:q])
   @reuniones = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
   @reuniones = @q.result.includes(:planta).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 end

 def cancelprov
   r = Reunion.find(params[:id])
   r.provecancela  #Aqui quiero  que guarde el input
   r.nombreprovee = User.find(current_user.id).name
   r.emailprove2  = User.find(current_user.id).email
   r.cancelprov = true
   r.save(validate: false)
   redirect_to action: "show", id: r.id
 end  

 def show
 end

 # GET /reuniones/new
def new
  Time.zone = 'America/Bogota' 
  @reunion = Reunion.new(fecha_entrega: Time.zone.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), hora_inicio: Time.zone.now, hora_final: Time.zone.now) 
end

# GET /reuniones/1/edit
def edit
 end

 # POST /reuniones
 # POST /reuniones.json
 def create
   @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)
    respond_to do |format|
     if @reunion.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
     else         
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end

 # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1
 # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1.json
 def update
  respond_to do |format|

    if @reunion.update(reunion_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Formación exitosa' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reunion }   
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /reuniones/1
# DELETE /reuniones/1.json
def destroy
  @reunion.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to reuniones_url, notice: 'Reunion was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_reunion
    @reunion = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def reunion_params
  params.require(:reunion).permit(:hora_pedido, :fecha_pedido,
  :hora_inicio, :hora_final, :fecha_entrega, :observacion, :subtotal,:atencion,
  :planta_id, :ubicacion,:hora_entre,:nombre,:puntualidad,:fullid,
  :variedad,:presentacion,:reunionfullnombre,:producto_id,:cantidad,:valor,:reunionvalor_id)
  .merge( areausolir: current_user.gerencia,  emailsoli: current_user.email, nombresoli: current_user.name)
end
```

end

Comment: @gerry ud sabe  sobre  esto  gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres enviar la forma utilizando un _link_?, ¿por qué no utilizar un botón?

Comment: @Gerry hola, el  link_to lo utilizo para guardar un boleano y todo lo que vez en el metodo cancelprov , y en el formulario es para guarda lo que hay en el input  que es string, entonces  lo que necesito  es que guarde lo que hay en el metodo y el input que hay en el formulario, gracias,  si no entiendes me repite la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la acción del controlador que recibe el `input` de la forma?

Comment: @Gerry ya lo actualize  mire a  ver,  o  sino se lo pongo todo el controlador, por que con el submit el guarda normal como si fuera un update.gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código completo del controlador?

Comment: @Gerry  ya  lo organice,gracias

Comment: @Gerry ya pudo ver el cambio_